# What is the reason for this query is not working? Got: MySQLSyntaxErrorException Unknown column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

My columns at customer table

```
cusid  cusname cusadress paidamount  email

cus123  damidu   kegalle  45           adfff
```

This is my Java query

```
String query = "UPDATE `customer` SET `cusname`='"+jTextField_name.getText()+"',`cusadress`='"+jTextField_adress.getText()+"',`paidamount`='"+jTextField_amount.getText()+"',`email`="+jTextField_emailuser.getText()+" WHERE `cusid` = "+jTextField_id.getText();
executeSQlQuery(query, "Updated");
```

Error

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'cus123' in 'where clause'
```

What is the reason for this update is not working , but insert and delete statement works?

Comment: 1) Possible SQL Injection 2) Use parameter binding instead of concatenatig SQL string 3) **`cus123` != `'cus123'`**

Comment: Use a preparedStatement

Comment: query like that is mess. try to use preparedStatement.

Comment: I have tried many ways but the same error comes , is the java code coreect sir

Comment: No it is not correct as outlined in the very first comment

Comment: @luciano-van-der-veekens I rolled back your edit as you seemed to change the actual code

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't recall changing the code. What did I do?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens Sorry maybe it is me, as Alex seems to have done the same **but** it looks like `WHERE cusid = ` gets changed to `WHERE ``cusid`` = ` - maybe the backticks were just not showing up originally - if so please accept my apology

Comment: @ScaryWombat Useful note: viewing the edit in side-by-side markdown is usually more useful when looking at an edit that did something like changing non-code to code, as that only highlights the indent and shows the rest of the text as the same.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks I did not know that

Answer (score 3):

Use PreparedStatement like this below :

```
String updateQuery = "UPDATE customer SET cusname=?,cusadress=?,paidamount=?,email=? WHERE cusid=?";

PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(updateQuery); // con is reference variable of Connection class
        stmt.setString(1, jTextField_name.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, jTextField_adress.getText());
        stmt.setInt(3, jTextField_amount.getText());
        stmt.setString(4, jTextField_emailuser.getText());
        stmt.setString(5, jTextField_id.getText());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems to me that `cusid` is not Numeric, it is String based. But `paidamount` looks like a Numeric based

Comment: @AlexK Thanks for the clarificarion. I was assuming, it should be Numberic. WIll update it

Comment: I agree with you. It was just a minor remark :)

Comment: thnk you sir  i will try that

Comment: @DamiduRathnayaka Sure